# Passing Variable to Javascript for Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a system which currently outputs a table of results in html for the browser.

These results can be updated by clicking the approveCredit button on each row.

I'd like to create a javascript catch which looks out for the button click and passes the given variable from the row and performs an ajax task.

Code:

**PHP to echo table of results**

```
<tbody>
 <?php 
 $count = 1;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))  
 {?>

 <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $count++;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['user_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['credits'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['notes'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['po'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date_received'];?></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default approveCredit" type="button" value="<?php echo $row['credits'];?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Approve Credit Request"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  <?php } ?>    
  </tbody>
```

**Javascript Awaiting Button Click**

```
$('.approveCredit').on('click', function() {

        var creditid = $('.approveCredit').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax url to update database",
            type: "POST",
            data: {creditid: creditid},
            success: successFunction,
            error: errorFunction
        });

});
```

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: Try this: `var creditid = $(this).attr('val');`

Comment: apologies, it doesn't work @JonStirling!

Comment: Define "doesn't work" . What bit doesn't work (even if we can guess), what does it give you, what were you expecting etc etc. All useful information.

Comment: Seems my problem has been solved, thanks to Sajitha Nilan.

Comment: I update my answer with more details. If it is correct please accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
actually you must use Jquery attr to get value from the ancher

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default approveCredit" type="button" value="<?php echo $row['credits'];?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Approve Credit Request"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
```

value is an attribute of the ancher. So you should use it like this,

```
var creditid = $('.approveCredit').attr('value');
```

and also preventing default action of ancher (a tag) change your code as this

```
$('.approveCredit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var creditid = $('.approveCredit').attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax url to update database",
            type: "POST",
            data: {creditid: creditid},
            success: successFunction,
            error: errorFunction
        });

});
```